# How can I get horizontal overflows to work in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm a newbie when it comes to CSS.  My overall goal is to convert a small web application that I have which displays data in table to using CSS.

A description of what the application displays is that in a left hand window there is a list of employee names, on the right is a cell for each day that the employee has worked which spans a user selectable period.

In the code below, I can't get the cell elements to overflow so that the user can scroll to the right, instead the cells are overflowing down.

Is there a way I can get the overflow to work horizontally rather than vertically so I can scroll left and right to see all the cells rather than what it is doing now which is creating a scroll bar vertically?

Much appreciated if anyone can help - it's got me frustrated!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS Layout</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="centreposition">
        <div id="centrecontent">
        <?php 
            for ($counter = 0; $counter < 100; $counter++)
            {
                ?> 
                <div id="cell">AB</div> 
                <?php      
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">Footer.</div>

 <div id="left">Left <div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#header {
    height: 100px;
        background-color: #9FF300;
}

#centreposition {
        width: 600px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

#centrecontent {
    z-index: 100;
    min-width: 1px;
        height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 4px;
        background-color: #FFFF00;
        overflow-x: scroll; 
}


#footer {
    padding-left: 175px;
    background-color: #20F3F7;
}

#left {
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 6px;
}



#right {
    width: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 200px;
}

#cell {
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: #aaccdd;
    font-size: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-color: #555555;
}
```

Comment: What would be wrong with using a table? Using tables for tabular data is **never** the wrong thing to do.

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same id, concatenate "cell" with $counter to improve it.

Comment: An aside: i'd recommend using the html5 doctype (``<!DOCTYPE html>``) for simplicity's sake, unless you absolutely need to use html4.

Comment: you can either increase height & width of #centrecontent or use HTML table.

Comment: @Graeme Cowie As others have already pointed out about using html tables, `<div>` by default occupies an entire "line" so they would naturally fall into a vertical stacking format.  Notice in MiniRagnarok's solution, he is setting everything with class `cell` to `float:left` and has specific width. This tells them to start floating together towards the left... but again, a better solution is probably using html tables instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. You're essentially asking for a table-based layout, so you may as
   well use an HTML table.
2. Each of your cells has a fixed width, and your PHP code should know
   how many of them to create, so you can set the width of the
   container element (#centrecontent here) wide enough to contain them
   all.

Also, element IDs are supposed to be unique within the HTML doc, so creating 100 elements all with #cell as their ID is incorrect - you should use a CSS class name instead.

Comment: OK thanks guys, I've kept the data inside a table as you're right, it is actually a table of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of the cells in another `div` and set that `div` to a specific width.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRruT/)